# How to extract font-family in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I am currently working on an [HTML utility](http://chethan.co.in/htmlhelper). I want to extract the font-family used in the HTML Code using Javascript. I found this piece of Regular Expression which can find only the normal fonts:

```
font-family\s*?:.*?(;|(?=""|'|;))
```

i.e font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif

I am not able to match font families like:

```
font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
```

Are there any methods available to extract the fonts/font families?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it sorted out..

```
function demo(input,output) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
try {
    div.innerHTML = input;
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
    return;
}
// images
var images = div.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
//console.log(images);

// font-family
var fontfamily = [];
var ffstack = [div];
while (ffstack.length) {
    var ff = ffstack.pop();
    if (ff.style && ff.style.fontFamily) {
            fontfamily.push(ff.style.fontFamily);
    }
    if (ff.childNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ff.childNodes.length; i++) {
            ffstack.push(ff.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
//console.log(fontfamily);
document.getElementById("resultBlock").style.display = "block";
var vArray = Duplicates(fontfamily);
var fontss = vArray.join("\n\n");
output.value =fontss;
```

}

```
function Duplicates(arr) {
var i,
lenn = arr.length,
    out = [],
    obj = {};

for (i = 0; i < lenn; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = 0;
}
for (i in obj) {
    out.push(i);
}
return out;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery you can just:

```
$('#myElement').css('fontFamily');
```

Or webkit solution:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#myElement');
window.getComputedStyle(el).fontFamily;
```

And if you still plan to match from a text like css/style definition:

```
"font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;".match(/font-family\s*?\:(.*)(?=;)/gi)
```

It's a simplest RegExp, but will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Non-jQuery solution:

```
var element = document.getElementById('elementId'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('font-family');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the font family by this simple script.

```
alert(document.getElementById("*** id name of your field******").style.fontFamily);
```